# Displaying INNER JOIN-ed data with DATE_FORMAT-ted data not yet working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm developing a work order system for a client. Data is entered through an admin panel, such as `Client`, `Category` and `Description`. The database is set up to record `Updated` and `Created` information.

Initially, the `Category` was typed in (DB table was `VARCHAR`) and when the DB was queried, all of the information would properly display on the main page.

The query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *,
    DATE_FORMAT(wo_updated,"%m/%d/%Y") AS updated,
    DATE_FORMAT(wo_created, "%m/%d/%Y") AS created
    FROM work_orders
    ORDER BY wo_id ASC';
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
```

This works perfect, displaying the `Client`, `Description`, `Category` as well as the `Updated` and `Created` information, these two displayed as `10/07/2013` for example.

Then I added a section to the admin panel that allowed categories to be entered and stored in the DB so that when entering a new work order, you would choose from a pre-set list of categories in order to keep things looking smooth and consistent.

Here's the new query, sans the DATE_FORMAT code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, cat_name
    FROM work_orders INNER JOIN categories
    ON work_orders.wo_category = categories.cat_id
    ORDER BY wo_id ASC';
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
```

This works perfectly, displaying the `Client`, `Description` and `Category` (`Category` now called from the `categories` DB table which is now `INT`).

But as you'll notice, I don't have the `DATE_FORMAT`-ted code in the second query as every attempt I have made to marry the two ends up in a syntax error. I can do one or the other, but I can't yet combine the two queries that display `DATE_FORMAT`-ted `Updated` and `Created` information from the `work_orders` table in conjunction with the `cat_name` information from the `categories` table.

I have tried sub-queries and a variety of attempts on the various JOIN commands, but as yet, I still can't get past the MySQLi syntax error. Obviously, there is something here I need to learn, and after several hours of trial and error on top of much research, I'm stuck. Any help to solve this problem, which may well be quite simple, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

This is one approach I tried that led to the syntax error:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, cat_name
    DATE_FORMAT(wo_updated,"%m/%d/%Y") AS updated,
    DATE_FORMAT(wo_created, "%m/%d/%Y") AS created
    FROM work_orders INNER JOIN categories
    ON work_orders.wo_category = categories.cat_id
    ORDER BY wo_id ASC';
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
```

**FURTHER UPDATE:**

I wish I could say that the missing comma hasn't bitten me before, the missing comma was the culprit! Thank you @SergeyRonin, @denlau, @JMS786, you were ALL right about the comma. Thanks also for the code suggestions, I don't know who to credit with the correct answer since you all had it.

Comment: Could you please show the query where you was trying use DATE_FORMAT-ed column with INNER JOIN?

Comment: @SergeyRonin Updated, please see above. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    wo.*, 
    c.cat_name,
    DATE_FORMAT(wo.`wo_updated`,"%m/%d/%Y") AS updated,
    DATE_FORMAT(wo.`wo_created`, "%m/%d/%Y") AS created
FROM work_orders wo
INNER JOIN categories c ON wo.`wo_category` = c.`cat_id`
ORDER BY wo.`wo_id` ASC
```

Also, in your code you missed comma after `cat_name`, so this may be reason you have error too.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma after "cat_name" in line one. Your query should look like this:

```
    SELECT 
        w.wo_updated as wo_updated,
        w.wo_created as wo_updated,
        c.cat_name as cat_name,
        DATE_FORMAT(w.wo_updated,"%m/%d/%Y") AS updated,
        DATE_FORMAT(w.wo_created, "%m/%d/%Y") AS created
    FROM 
        work_orders w
    INNER JOIN 
        categories c
        ON 
            w.wo_category = c.cat_id
    ORDER BY 
        w.wo_id ASC
```

Well, I've given the tables some shorter names - your call if you want to use that.
Furthermore I explicitly calls the fields, I need in my SELECT-statement. This is due to the idea, that you should only get exactly the information, you need. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the comma "," between cat_name and DATE_FORMAT...